# Django 403 Javascript Post Fetch

Tags: javascript, python, django

I've been trying to POST an audio file from browser to Django using JS.
The object is on a FormData.

```
function makeLink(){
  let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type })
  let fd = new FormData;
  fd.append("audioRecording", blob);
  fetch("/home/django/django_project/static/audio", {method:"POST", body:fd})
  .then(response => response.ok)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

I have added decorators for exempting csfr.

Like this:

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie
@csrf_exempt
def audio(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Why is this still returning 403?

Comment: This `/home/django/django_project/static/audio` seems wrong. This is a path. It should be an url.

Comment: @Kornikopic You were right. Where do I specify where to upload? Nginx conf?

Comment: Instead of mentioned path, just use URL... `fetch("URL_GOES_HERE")` [Read more about how to use `fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).